# How can I read a pasted image into RichTextBox and display it into an image box in WInForm c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Chat application and want users to be able to paste an image into a rich text box. When they click the send button in the chat app, I need to know how to read that image from the RTB and display the image in a picture box inside the chat bubble...

I use a tool to take a screen snipit. I then paste that image into the rich text box with ctrl v on keyboard. The image is pasted into the rtb but when I click send I cannot find how to read the vakue

Once I can read the image value from the RTB, I will then know how to send the image across the wire and show it on the other end.

[image]

Comment: What action a user needs to perform to paste stuff inside the RTB? Do you provide a context menu with a Paste selection? If you do, calling `[RichTextBox].Paste()`, you can override WndProc, get the `WM_PASTE` message and then inspect the Clipboard. Otherwise, if you allow the keyboard shortcuts, you have to trap `WM_NOTIFY` + `EN_CLIPFORMAT` (since the shortcuts won't generate `WM_PASTE` messages)

Comment: Well, you could also *disable* the keyboard shortcuts (suppressing `CTRL+V` / `SHIFT+INS`) and call Paste() yourself instead, so you always get a `WM_PASTE` message and you can act on it.